# React Native Flatlist Error onViewableItemsChanged

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-android, react-flatlist

I have a horizontal scrolling flatlist in my app. But onViewableItemsChanged keeps throwing an error. 'Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported.' I write the codes below. Please help me!

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null);
const [currentSectionIndex, setCurrentSectionIndex] = useState(0);

const onButtonPress = useCallback(() => {
    if (currentSectionIndex === searchedData?.length - 1) {
        // What you want to do at the end of the list.
    } else if (flatListRef.current) {
        // Go to the next item
        flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
            index: currentSectionIndex + 1,
        });
        setCurrentSectionIndex(currentSectionIndex + 1);
    }
}, [currentSectionIndex, searchedData?.length]);

const onLeftButtonPress = useCallback(() => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
            index: currentSectionIndex - 1,
        });
        setCurrentSectionIndex(currentSectionIndex - 1);
}, [currentSectionIndex, searchedData?.length]);

const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100,
    waitForInteraction: true,
    minimumViewTime: 5,
})

const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length >= 1) {
        setCurrentSectionIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
    }
}, [])

<FlatList
       ref={flatListRef} 
       horizontal
       pagingEnabled // cause snapping to items
       data={data}
       keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig.current}
       onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged} 
 />
{currentSectionIndex!==searchedData?.length-1&&!enteredString?<>
          <View> //splinter
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>onButtonPress()}>
               <Entypo name={'chevron-thin-right'} size={38} color={'#fff'}/>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
 </>:null}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove **onViewableItemsChanged** from **Flatlist** write it like the below code, because on react-native: "71" newer versions doesn't support old way.

```js
  const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({viewableItems, changed}) => {
      // apply your logic here
  }, []);

  const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef([
    {viewabilityConfig, onViewableItemsChanged},
  ]);


<FlatList
       ref={flatListRef} 
       horizontal
       pagingEnabled // cause snapping to items
       data={data}
       keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={
           viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current
       }
       viewabilityConfig={{viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50}}
 />
```